# Как лучше сделать страницу категории для Custom Post Type?

Tags: wordpress

подскажите как лучше сделать
У меня есть продукты сделанные через custom post type( их штук 30 , и оплата не будет , т.е Wocoommerce здесь не нужен)

Вопрос такой, мне надо сделать следующих структуру
Страница продукта где выводится категории 0 уровня
При клике на названия категории переходим на страницу где выводится подкатегории
И при клике на подкатегории - уже вывод самих продуктов
Вопрос такой

Страница вывода категории и подкатегории - писать в archive-products.php? Либо archive-products.php надо писать вывод товаров
А куда тогда писать шаблон вывода категории и подкатегории,
Именно надо что бы на странице site.ru/products - был вывод каталога категории. Т.е страница со всеми продуктами независимо от категории - не должно быть

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **single-product.php** - Страница товара
- **taxonomy-product_cat.php** - Страница категории
- **/template-parts/archive-product.php** - 1 товар на
  архивной странице
- **/template-parts/archive-product_cat.php** - 1
  категория на архивной странице

Вывести 1 товар товар на архивной странице примерно так:

```
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    get_template_part( '/template-parts/archive', 'product_cat' );
}
```

Comment: По моему ты не понял вопрос ТСа. get_template_part никаким боком к вопросу ТСа  - подключаемые им "запчасти шаблонов"  это НЕ шаблоны.